# Flutter - Google Maps marker cannot be dragged

Tags: flutter

I have Google Maps in my Flutter app in which I have set a marker.
The Marker is set to `draggable:true` but still I cannot drag it.
Please help.

I am stuck for 3 days and there is no answer I could find on google.

Comment: Show please your  code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try holding your marker for a second before dragging it. I also had the same problem and after holding for a second and dragging it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks brother. I was thinking that is is due to some error in the plugin